# Explanation of str.partition() in python

Tags: python, string, partitioning

I am having a hard time understanding `str.partition()` function in python.  I have read the definition of the function and searched online without finding an explanation that makes sense to me.

I have some code that uses it pretty heavily and have been trying to understand it.  I could post the code if it would help but it is a pretty precise code segment that would probably complicate things.

Need in-depth, probably low-level, explanation of `str.partition()` function in python.

Comment: It is a little disappointing to see a serious question down voted.  I stated that I researched and did not understand.  I feel my question was very clear and can be very useful in the future for someone in the same boat as me.

Comment: Don't take it too personally.  The down votes may have come from the lack of code in your question, though it's hard to tell for certain.  Voting is a personal choice for each member.  Ideally, someone who down votes should provide a comment explaining why, but that's not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are pretty clear ...

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

So ...

```
>>> 'test'.partition('s')
('te', 's', 't')
>>> 'test'.partition('a')
('test', '', '')
```

You either get the front, splitter character, and tail, or you get the full string and two blank strings (depending on whether or not the partition character is present).

Comment: WOW!! Thank you so much.  For some reason this blew right over my head.  I guess that is what hours of staring at code will do.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: This doesn't really explain _why_ you'd want to use `s.partition(sep)` over `s.split(sep, 1)` (and vice-versa). First, `partition` lets you match the separator. More importantly, however, `s.partition(sep)` always returns 3 values (with the latter two empty if `sep` wasn't found), while `split` may return either 2 values or 1 (if `sep` wasn't found), which means you can write `first, sep, rest = s.partition(sep)` and it will always succeed, while `first, rest = s.split(sep, 1)` will raise a `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

Comment: I am using this method to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`. I am using `port+" inet "` as the `sep`.  So really it would be `eth8 inet `.  The line I am trying to find and change would be `iface eth8 inet static` and to change `static` to `dhcp`.  Does the cursor stay directly after where it found the `sep`?  I am a little confused by the code I am taking over.  It of course is not working.